# How to find unused white spaces in the new file using git command

Tags: git

As my project files are in the git, I have used the following command to find the changes before committing the file in git.

In command line

```
> git diff [filename]
```

The command displays the changes including unused white spaces for the existing git file. but it doesn't work in the new file.

How to find the new file unused white spaces?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Can you quantify `unused white spaces` by giving us an example?

Comment: `code` 
if ($name === 'angular') {         
   return 'angular';
}
`code`

After { there are some unused white spaces.

Comment: This doesn't help to clarify your question.

Comment: do you mean that git should ignore is the changes is just a whitespace?

Comment: I think you're using the word "unused" wrong. Try explaining what you mean in more than one word.

Answer (score 2):

OP probably searches for `git diff --check` alternative for new files:

```
git add [filename]
git diff --staged --check [filename]
git restore --staged [filename] (or git reset HEAD [filename])
```

Answer (score -1):

I *think* you are referring to Git's white-space highlighting features in `git diff` output.  It is hard to show this in pure plain-text, of course, but if we replace the actual blank with an underscore, we might have a diff that includes this:

```
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
...
-some_text_on_a_line
+some_text_on_a_line_
```

The final blank (or underscore in this example) is colored background-red instead of foreground-green (when this kind of highlighting is enabled, and using all the default color settings).

The claim is:

> The command displays the changes including unused white spaces for the existing git file. but it doesn't work in the new file.

But this is simply wrong: if `git diff` will highlight trailing (or, in certain cases, embedded) white space, it will do so in new files as well.

Most likely, your issue is that you did:

```
$ git status
```

and got:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    new.txt
```

where `git diff` does not show the file at all, and then did:

```
$ git add new.txt
```

and ran `git diff`, which once again does not show the file at all, because now `git diff` is comparing the *index* version of `new.txt` to the *work-tree* version of `new.txt`, and those two match.

To view the desired diff, you should compare the *committed* version of `new.txt` (which does not exist, so Git uses `/dev/null` as a placeholder empty file) to the index version:

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/new.txt b/new.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..2459b89
--- /dev/null
+++ b/new.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+new file
+this line ends with a blank_
+this one doesn't
```

(where I replaced the highlighted blank with an underscore).

Note that Git's diff highlighting is quite tune-able, through both [command line options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) and [`git config` settings](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  The main controls are `core.whitespace`, setting sets what to consider as "whitespace errors", with `diff.wsErrorHighlight` controlling which parts of a diff are colored according to `color.diff.whitespace`.  All of this assumes that `color.diff` is `true`, or is `auto` and subsequently enabled (see also `color.ui`).